# RedBlack Tree insertion method does not work

Tags: java, data-structures, red-black-tree

I'm trying to implement RedBlack tree insert method but it does not work as expected. Here's the source code.

Insert method:

```
void insert( int key ) { root = insert( null, root, key ); root.color = BLACK; }
  private Node insert( Node parent, Node root, int key )
  {

    //STEP 1 : Classic BST insertion
    if ( root == null )
      return ( new Node( parent, key, RED ) );

    boolean isLeft;
    if ( key < root.key )
    {
      root.left = insert( root, root.left, key);
      isLeft = true;
    }
    else
    {
      root.right = insert( root, root.right, key);
      isLeft = false;
    }

    //STEP2: Self balancing the tree.
    if ( isLeft )
    {
      if ( root.color == RED && root.left.color == RED )
      {
        Node sibling = findSibling( root );
        if ( ! isRed( sibling ) )
        {
          if ( isLeftChild( root ) )
          {
            return rightRotate( root, true );
          }
          else
          {
            //recolore( root );
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // mirror case
      // yet to do
    }

    return root;
  }
```

RightRotate method + other used methods:

```
 private Node rightRotate( Node newRoot, boolean changeColor )
      {
        Node oldRoot = newRoot.parent;
        oldRoot.left = newRoot.right;
        newRoot.right = oldRoot;
        newRoot.parent = oldRoot.parent;
        oldRoot.parent = newRoot;

        if ( changeColor )
        {
          root.color = BLACK;
          root.parent.color = RED;
        }
        return newRoot;
      }

private Node findSibling( Node root )
  {
    Node parent = root.parent;
    if ( parent.left == root )
      return parent.right;
    return parent.left;
  }

  private boolean isRed( Node root )
  {
    if ( root == null )
      return false;
    return root.color == RED;
  }

  private boolean isLeftChild( Node root )
  {
    if ( root.parent == null )
      return false;

    if ( root.parent.left == root )
      return true;

    return false;
  }
```

Main + preoder print of the tree:

```
void preOrder() { preOrder( root ); }
  private void preOrder( Node root )
  {
    if ( root != null )
    {
      System.out.print( " | " + ( root.color ? "RED" : "BLACK" ) + " " + root.key + " |" );
      preOrder( root.left );
      preOrder( root.right );
    }
  }

}

class Main
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    RedBlackBST tree = new RedBlackBST();
    tree.insert( 3 );
    tree.insert( 2 );
    tree.insert( 1 );

    tree.preOrder();
  }
}
```

This implementation is not finished yet and should only work for Left Left case ( like in the main method 3,2,1 ) that means I have to make right rotation.

Expected output should be:

```
| BLACK 2 | | RED 1 | | RED 3 |
```

instead of this output i get

```
 | BLACK 3 | | BLACK 2 | | RED 1 | | BLACK 3 | | BLACK 2 | | RED 1 | ... // infinity loop
```

Could anyone tell me where do I do a mistake? Obviously I do not wan't you to post the whole code but just a suggestion how to fix that and why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should first perform a binary search tree insert, and then repair the insert as it could now be imbalanced, There are 4 different cases you should account for when re balancing, the following code shows them. Here is the code in C# (it should be easy to convert it to java ) In the following code T1 is the type of the keys in the tree nodes, and T2 is the type of the values in tree nodes. The implementation is generic.

```
    public RedBlackTreeNode<T1, T2> Insert(RedBlackTreeNode<T1, T2> root, RedBlackTreeNode<T1, T2> newNode)
            {
                root = Insert_BST(root, newNode); /* is normal bst insert.*/
                Insert_Repair(root, newNode);

                root = newNode;
                while (root.Parent != null)
                {
                    root = root.Parent;
                }
                return root;
            }
 private void Insert_Repair(RedBlackTreeNode<T1, T2> root, RedBlackTreeNode<T1, T2> newNode)
        {   
           if (newNode.Parent == null && newNode.Color == Color.Red) /* Property: the root is black. */
                {
                    newNode.FlipColor();
                }
                else if (newNode.Parent != null && newNode.Parent.Color == Color.Red) /* If this holds it means that both the new node and its parent are red, and in a red-black tree this is not allowed. Children of a red node should be black.*/
                {
                    var uncle = newNode.GetUncle();

                    if (uncle != null && uncle.Color == Color.Red) /* Both the parent and uncle of the new node are red. Note that a null uncle is considered black. */
                    {
                        newNode.Parent.Color = Color.Black;
                        uncle.Color = Color.Black;
                        newNode.GetGrandParent().Color = Color.Red;
                        Insert_Repair(root, newNode.GetGrandParent()); /* Repeat repair on the grandparent, as by the re-coloring the previous layers could have been messed up. */
                    }
                    else if (uncle == null || uncle.Color == Color.Black)
                    {`enter code here`
                        if (newNode.FormsTriangle() && newNode.IsLeftChild())
                        {
                            RotateRight(newNode.Parent);
                            newNode = newNode.RightChild; /* After rotation new node has become the parent of its former parent.*/
                            /* Triangle is transformed to a line.*/
                        }
                        else if (newNode.FormsTriangle() && newNode.IsRightChild())
                        {
                            RotateLeft(newNode.Parent);
                            newNode = newNode.LeftChild; /* After rotation new node has become the parent of its former parent.*/
                            /* Triangle is transformed to a line.*/
                        }

                        /* When reaching at this point, we might or might not have gone through above two triangle forms, as the alignment could have already been a line.*/
                        var grandParent = newNode.GetGrandParent();
                        if (newNode.IsRightChild())
                        {
                            RotateLeft(grandParent);
                        }
                        else if (newNode.IsLeftChild())
                        {
                            RotateRight(grandParent);
                        }
                        newNode.Parent.Color = Color.Black;
                        if (grandParent != null)
                            grandParent.Color = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
           }
```